# java - use of ternary operator

Tags: java, ternary-operator

I got quite a large code with 4 different conditions which I tried to shorten using the conditional ternary operator as [descibed here](http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018). However, I can't manage the right syntax since I have more than 2 conditions. Could someone explain how to use the ternary operator in such case? My code goes below

And no, I'm not asking to write code for me, I'm looking for an explanation of ternary operator use with multiple conditions

```
     if (mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000 / 60 < 10
            && mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000 % 60 < 10) {
        tvTimeElapsed.setText("0"
                + Integer.toString(mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000 / 60)
                + ":" + "0"
                + Integer.toString(mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000 % 60));

    } else if (mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000 / 60 < 10
            && mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000 % 60 >= 10) {

        tvTimeElapsed.setText("0"
                + Integer.toString(mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000 / 60)
                + ":"
                + Integer.toString(mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000 % 60));

    } else if (mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000 / 60 >= 10
            && mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000 % 60 < 10) {

        tvTimeElapsed
                .setText(Integer.toString(mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000 / 60)
                        + ":"
                        + "0"
                        + Integer.toString(mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000 % 60));

    } else {

        tvTimeElapsed
                .setText(Integer.toString(mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000 / 60)
                        + ":"
                        + Integer.toString(mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000 % 60));

    }
```

Comment: You'll simply have to nest several conditional operations in each other. But that's ugly, and hard to read. So don't. =)

Comment: The usual advice is: don't!  Trying to embed multiple conditions with multiple nested `?:` just results in code that's hard to read.

Comment: I would question why you're trying to shorten it. Short code isn't always better. As it stands, the code you've posted is quite complicated anyway, so IMO refactoring it to use ternary operators would make it incredibly unreadable

Comment: well my class is already large and implements serveral interfaces, so I thought shortening the code whenever possible would be a good practice

Comment: I agree with the previous comments about readability. But for your understanding, you can nest ternary operators: `a ? b : (c ? d : (e ? f : g))`

Comment: I think you can use `int value1 = mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000 / 60;` and `int value2 = mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000 % 60;` instead of calculating them again in each if block. Also the code snippet would become smaller and easier to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just this, without any ternaries at all:

```
int seconds = mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
tvTimeElapsed.setText(
    String.format("%02d:%02d", seconds / 60, seconds % 60);
);
```

You don't need to reinvent the wheel with all these conditions here: there's an internal Java string formatter for all these hard choices and stuff. )

Comment: shame on me I haven't thought of that. Thanks m8

Answer (score 1):

I must agree with all comments: it's ugly.

```
String textToSet = (mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000 / 60 < 10 ? 
( mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000 % 60 < 10 ? "0"
                + Integer.toString(mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000 / 60)
                + ":" + "0"
                + Integer.toString(mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000 % 60) : "0"
                + Integer.toString(mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000 / 60)
                + ":"
                + Integer.toString(mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000 % 60)) : 
( mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000 % 60 < 10 ? "0"
                + Integer.toString(mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000 / 60)
                + ":"
                + Integer.toString(mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000 % 60) : Integer.toString(mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000 / 60)
                        + ":"
                        + "0"
                        + Integer.toString(mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000 % 60)) )
```

With replacement of the Integer :

```
Integer int1 = mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000 / 60;
Integer int2 = mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000 % 60;

tvTimeElapsedText = (int1< 10 ? 
                        (int2 < 10 ? 
                            "0" + Integer.toString(int1) + ":" + "0" + Integer.toString(int2) :
                            "0" + Integer.toString(int1) + ":" + Integer.toString(int2)
                        ) :
                        (int2 < 10 ? 
                            Integer.toString(int1) + ":" + "0" + Integer.toString(int2) :
                            Integer.toString(int1) + ":" + Integer.toString(int2)
                        )
                    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Removed the first part

**Edit:**

```
int var1 = mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000 / 60;
int var2 = mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000 % 60;

String hour = var1 < 10 ? "0" + var1 : var1;
String minute = var1 < 10 ? "0" + var2 : var2;

String complete = hour + ":" + minute;
```